# How can you give an object a value in android studio?

Tags: java, oop

I am new to programming. I cannot understand most of oop. I am trying to make a custom array adapter, but I do not understand how can you assign a value to an object for example: `LayoutInflater myinflater=  LayoutInflater.from(getContext());` I always thought that when creating an object you use it just for the methods the class has and to call its constructor `LayoutInflator myinflator = new LayoutInflator();`
I hate memorizing something I do not understand and end up looking at every  class that is used in tutorials but end up getting more confused. Can someone please also tell me the best way of learning Android Studio for beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of classes (instantiable and static -- instantiable is the default, so there's no keyword associated).  Instantiable classes can be instantiated, with `new Classname(constructor,arguments,here)`.  Static classes can't be instantiated, and usually refer to something that simply exists in the programmer's conceptual space of the program.  (For example, on desktop computers, programs have an Environment that contains variables that can be set in memory before the program is started.  Since there's only one Environment, it is a static class.)

There are also two types of methods (instance and static -- again, instance is the default, so there's no keyword associated).  Instance methods act on data associated with an instance of the object (i.e., something that you can put in a variable of type Classname), and they need to be called with `variablename.InstanceMethodName(args)`.  Static methods, on the other hand, refer to something that is always the same across all the times you use a class, and are often called "utility methods".  These are referred to by `Classname.StaticMethodName(args)`.  (Also, static classes can contain static methods, but not instance methods.  This is because they can never be instantiated, so there's never any instance for instance methods to be able to operate on.)

There are some times when you don't want to use a constructor for an instantiable class.  One of these times is when the processing needed to create the class can throw an exception.  (It's generally considered bad form for a constructor to get into a state where it could throw.)

Looking at your example, `new LayoutInflator(getContext())` could potentially throw if it's passed something that it didn't expect, or if the Context it received didn't have the correct values that it expected.  So, there's a static utility method that performs the `new LayoutInflator()` call, and then hooks up the things that need to be hooked up and sets the values that need to be set in the new LayoutInflator instance it just constructed so that it operates properly in the context you created it in.  But, because it can only do that by getting information from the Context that it's passed, it could potentially throw if it tries to access a Context member that's null at the time it accesses it.

Most books I've seen have glossed over these concepts, and I know that my explanation might be confusing for you.  That's why there's a chance for multiple people to answer.

And, here's some information to help you with this site in the future.  What you're looking for is a book or course on Android programming.  A quick search finds https://www.onlineprogrammingbooks.com/android/ as a potential resource, but I have not vetted the quality of these books; you could potentially also find Android programming courses either online or at a local community college.  Also, you're not really asking about "doing something in Android Studio", you're asking about "doing something in the language used to program Android devices, which you program with Android Studio".  And finally, the last question you asked ("what is the best way to learn Android programming using Android Studio?") would generally have the entire question closed as being too basic and broad for the site ('best' is subjective, and what works for one person doesn't necessarily work for another).  But, I know how confusing everything can seem, and I want you to have a good experience here.  I hope that this answer helps in some small way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sjcaged! Your answer was just what I needed. I am trying really hard to understand oop and it seems very hard to learn java and android studio at the same time because I get frustrated very easily. I will start understanding every concept first and then going to another topic. I hope someday I will become a decent programmer just like you. Thank you!!!!

Comment: No problem! Could you maybe mark this answer as "accepted"? It would help out the rest of the site's users when they have a question similar to yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Creational design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern). [`LayoutInflater.from(Context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#from(android.content.Context)) is a `static` method, in that `static` method is an invocation of a constructor. Something has to call the constructor to create an instance. But that something could be internal to the class. See also `Singleton` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Elliott explained. it uses a Singletone Design pattern. which means that the class doesn't have any public constructors, which explains why you can't create an object from it using the `new` keyword.
take a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater) . notice that it has 2 protected constructors.